# programming in c++ basic thing

Tags: c++, function, return

I have a simple question, because I don't understand the functionality correctly. 
Having the code like that:

```
int function(a, b)
{
 return a*b;
}
```

it is clear for me that if a and b are int then it returns the result.
However having such:

```
int function1(arg1, arg2)
{
 //something
 if (B)
 {
  //do something
  return;
  }
 arg1[0] = variable1;
 arg1[1] = variable2;
 arg2 = variable3;
 return;
}
```

I want to name the interfaces, so inputs and outputs, and put the function body into the 'blackbox'. Inputs are those that are arguments of the function, am I correct? Then outputs is integer array **arg1** and the integer **arg2**, is that right? If so, how can input be output, or if I'm wrong how to identify it? 
Also, what happens if **B** is true, at the return point? Does a **function1** return nothing? If so, why is not void type? 
sorry for a little bit chaos and for such funny example, but thanks to that I'm gonna be able to understand the concept.

Comment: Not clear what you want to say. What is blackbox?

Comment: Your function arguments have no types. Is this pseudocode?

Comment: I think he is confused about the idiom in C/C++ where some inputs are modified and are thus also "outputs" versus a single output by return type thing

Comment: Have you tried compiling some actual C++ code that looks like this?  I'm about 72% sure the compiler won't let you return nothing if you've said you're returning an int (at least, outside of `main`).

Comment: I want to recognize inputs outputs, to know the rule of it (blackbox is something inside, function body), it's my pseudocode where I wanted to point out at once all things that are not clear for me. I'm quite sure also it won't compile :) the thing is why inputs can be outputs and how to recognize that. In matlab it's so simple.

Comment: Inputs can only be outputs if the function takes them in by pointer or reference.  You'll know whether it's possible by a `[]`, `*`, or `&` (and generally, lack of `const`) in the declaration for a given param.  You'll only really know for sure, though, by reading the code or some decent documentation.

Comment: In C++, all arguments are inputs. However some arguments may *point* or *refer* to other objects that the function may modify. In general you cannot tell, given the interface alone, whether any given function modifies anything. You need separate documentation for that, written by humans in a natural language.

Comment: ah okay, so idea is to send input by pointer or reference if I want to update it. First clear, then put new value and it doesn't have to be in **return** expression at the function end right? can I do such thing in a function returning void? if so, what would I need function with return for? probably while using this function as part of some equation, where I'd like to get some integer in its place, am I thinking good way?

Comment: Prefer functions that modify nothing and return the result by means of a `return` statement. Pass by reference when you need to modify a value that is too expensive or inconvenient to copy to the function and back. Avoid pointers altogether until you learn more of the language (and even then prefer smart pointers to raw ones).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is actually invalid C++:

```
int function(a, b)
{
 return a*b;
}
```

It is invalid because function parameters must have type, and `a` and `b` don't have a type specified.  This would be valid:

```
int function(int a, int b)
{
 return a*b;
}
```

If you want to design a function that can accept parameters of unspecified type, you can use templates for that:

```
template<class Val>  Val function(Val a, Val b)
{
  return a*b;
}
```

This will work for any type (such as `int`) so long as that type makes sense when used with `operator*` as with `a*b`.. For example, `std::string` won't work.

In C++, all functions that are declared to return a type must return that type at every return point.  That makes this code also invalid:

```
int function1(arg1, arg2)
{
 //something
 if (B)
 {
  //do something
  return;
  }
 arg1[0] = variable1;
 arg1[1] = variable2;
 arg2 = variable3;
 return;
}
```

You cannot return `void` from a function declared to return an `int`.  If you need to "escape" from a function that is declared to return something, you can throw an exception:

```
int function1(arg1, arg2)
{
 //something
 if (B)
 {
  //do something
  throw std::runtime_error("whoops");
  }
 arg1[0] = variable1;
 arg1[1] = variable2;
 arg2 = variable3;
 throw std::runtime_error("whoops 2");
}
```

However, given the context of this question I suspect this is **not** what you're looking for, and you should consider exceptions to be an advanced topic for now.  these are not the droids you're looking for.

Comment: I have some c++ knowledge, in sense, I know usage of templates for example. I'm just now a bit confused with inputs outputs and when I have so many returns, some nested in if's conditions. Can you tell me how to put **try** and **catch** part of exception in such a case? If I get it right, under fullfilled B condition whoops is thrown and it jumps out of function1 ... to place where catch is, or try is?

Comment: I **really** don't think that exceptions are the right tool for the job here, given my understanding of what you're trying to accomplish.  However, to answer your question, you surround the call to `function` in the `try` block, and follow that immediately with a series of `catch` blocks.  Again, I really doubt this is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If B is true, the function returns before the output array is filled, but you still need to return *something* because the function has an "int" return type.

As for whether the parameters are input parameters or output parameters, that's up to you. However, the convention in C++ is that input parameters are const (if they are pointers or references), and non-const if they are output paramenters:

```
int function1(const int* arg1, int* arg2) // arg1 is an in param, arg2 is an out param
```

Comment: thank you! Can I be sure in such case that reading function1 arguments I can build my inputs and outputs interface? Because I think a function can also modify some global variable, which is not among arguments. is it the case?